# Can't parse string to int.....exception is thrown each time

Tags: jsp

```
    String str;
    str = request.getParameter("quantity");


try{
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
    out.println(i);
}
catch(Exception ee){
      out.println(ee);
}
```

Each time the output is NumberFormatException......am unable to parse the string to integer

Comment: Check if the content of the string can be converted to `int` !!! If the String is numeric like "90" or alphanumeric like "90A" etc ...

Comment: Whats the value of str?

Comment: Value of str is 2..........but when it is shown in an html textbox, the value is something like 2/

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your number is too large to fit in an `int` or as @Noob UnChained suggested, check the content.

you can use this method to try parsing in case you don't always know the value:

```
    public static int parseWithDefault(String number, int defaultVal) {
         try {
              return Integer.parseInt(number);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              return defaultVal;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier. Try this. im assuming this is c#.
Oh, sorry I just noticed it said jsp. i believe the concept is the same, but I havent tried jsp before.

```
String str;
str = request.getParameter("quantity");
int newValue;


try{
    int.TryParse(str , out newValue);
    out.println(newValue);
}
catch(Exception ee){
    out.println(ee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the value of str.It can be something can not be converted to int like "st"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you debug your code and see what is the value of str and also check the NumberFormatException stack trace as it will tell what value it was trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do should be to ensure that the string can be completely converted into a number.

```
"48" --> a number
"--48" --> not a number
```

If needed, you should parse the string or use a regexp to remove non-numeric characters. For an extra safety, you may put a default number in your integer that fits with a default use case then call a `TryParse`. This way, whatever happens it won't crash your application but you can still log the error.